# Xterm with no Uppercase 'E'?

Tags: centos, terminal

I have a Mac with Snow Leopard (OS X 10.6.5). I have been using the Mac terminal utility for a year now with no problems. When using it locally, there are no problems. When I log into my Rackspace Cloud Server running CentOS 5.5, the capital-E does not print, it just beeps. If I type 'ABCDEF' it will echo on the command line: "ABCDF" and it will beep when the upper-case E is typed.

My keyboard is OK. I can type and see the uppercase E in any other program or even other terminal windows, just not the one at the Rackspace server.

Another quirk: I can start up an instance of nano on the Rackspace server and the uppercase E prints just fine while I'm in nano. I can execute a simple bash script that I've created in nano:

`echo "ABCDEF"`

And it will output 'ABCDEF'. What is going on? How do I correct this?

Comment: Not sure what's going on, but try hitting ctrl-v followed by E to see if it will show you what character the shell thinks you're typing?

Answer (score 2):

You probably have an incorrect key binding in your `~/.inputrc` file (or `bind` command in your `~/.bashrc`. Look for `"E": something` or similar.